# Remove last element in list

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

I am currently using a list in structs that looks like this:

This is a function in which removes elements from a list. I start with a for loop to go through the entire list. If i is less than the number of entries it enters an if statement. Then it the old position into a hold ptr. Makes the old on = to NULL and then moves the list so that the elements below take its spot.

Heres a sample list when I call this function:

100
125
150

When I do this and I want to remove 150 from the list it goes through but looses access to memory in the list -> wlist_ptr[i] -> eth_address. I then get a set fault. Is there any way around loosing track?

Comment: Why not post `struct wifilist_t` and the other structure definition - seems rather crucial to a sensible answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a big mistake in the loop.

Only one element is "moved up", and it's moved up after it's set to null.

So, this
            list -> wlist_ptr[i] = NULL;
            list->wlist_ptr[i-1] = list->wlist_ptr[i];

Needs to change to this to prevent moving the NULL up:

```
        list->wlist_ptr[i-1] = list->wlist_ptr[i];
        list -> wlist_ptr[i] = NULL;
```

But then, a loop is needed to iterate through the remainder of the list to move them up as well.  `memmove` is your friend for this.  Keep in mind too, that when that's done, you don't want to increase `i` for the next iteration, because the next element in the list will now be at the original `i` location.

Perhaps this will do the job:

```
struct wifi_info_t *wifilist_remove(struct wifilist_t * list, int user_address)
{
    int i;
    int count;
    struct wifi_info_t *ptr;
    ptr = NULL;

    count = wifilist_number_entries(list);

    // TODO: take out the ( ptr == NULL ) logic if more than one match needs to be
    //       removed.
    for(i=0; ( i < count ) && ( ptr == NULL ); i++)
    {
        if(list -> wlist_ptr[i] -> eth_address == user_address)
        {
            ptr = list -> wlist_ptr[i];
            if ( i < ( count - 1 ) )
                memmove(&(wlist_ptr[i]), &(wlist_ptr[i + 1]), (count - (i + 1)) * sizeof(wlist_ptr[0]));

            // TODO: decrement the length of the list returned by
            // wifilist_number_entries(list)
        }
    }
    if(ptr != NULL)
    {
        list->wlist_entries--;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Note that I just typed this here, so it may have syntax errors or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Some example:

```
struct wifi_info_t *wifilist_remove(struct wifilist_t * list, int user_address)
{
    int i;
    struct wifi_info_t *ptr;
    ptr = NULL;
    for(i=0; i < wifilist_number_entries(list); i++)
    {
        if(list -> wlist_ptr[i] -> eth_address == user_address)
        {
            ptr = list -> wlist_ptr[i];
            if(i != (wifilist_number_entries(list) -1))
            {
                //replace it with last element
                list -> wlist_ptr[i] = list -> wlist_ptr[wifilist_number_entries(list)-1];
                list -> wlist_ptr[wifilist_number_entries(list)-1] = ptr;
            }
            //you can use free and realloc there if you want
            list->wlist_entries--;
        }
    }
    //why? don't do that
    return ptr;
}
```